# How to solve mysql error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel-5

I have this simple php script:

```
<?php
$c = new mysqli("localhost", 'root', '');
echo($c->connect_error);
?>
```

My mysql credentials are correct but when I run the php script, it prints this error:  `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.
I started mysql and apache services using `service mysql start` and `service apache2 start`. When I type `mysql -u root -h localhost` on terminal, all goes well but not my script. I tried using laravel but still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong? Please help.
Regards

Comment: what's your file permissions

Comment: @GauravGupta -rwxrwxr-x 1 root root    76 May 27 12:14 zig.php

Comment: you are doing code on laravel or not? if on laravel then why other file you can do it in .env or database.php file for this

Comment: @GauravGupta I'm getting the same error in both laravel and pure php

Comment: could you share your laravel code of env and config here

Comment: @GauravGupta DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: @GauravGupta I'm thinking the problem might be from mysql configuration because that pure php code could have ran.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145261/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-sam-ziggler).

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution by running `update user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';`
The plugin was unix_socket before I did an update.